# Change the class of a div to that of a different CSS class using node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I have an index.html file that will contain some boxes that will default to green. I want to use node.js to change the colour of those boxes (by changing the div class from "red" to "green") based on a value I plan to get from a rest API (basically a 0 or a 1).

```
<div id="JIRA" class="small-box bg-green">
```

I want to be able to read index.html, then change:

```
class="small-box bg-green">
```

to

```
class="small-box bg-red">
```

Then write the change back to index.html before it is sent off to the user. I would use client side js for this but I can't expose the API token for security reasons.

I've seen cheerio and jsdom for parsing and manipulating the HTML but I've been unable to find an example of how to change the actual class. Is this possible with node.js?

Comment: Why would you use node.js (server-side language) to update live view, use JS and ajax.

Comment: Are you using a framework like [Express](https://expressjs.com/) to build and deliver your pages or are you handling all of that with Node yourself?

Comment: What are you using to send the html files?.. If your using node then have a look at say Express, here you can pick many different templating engine, these are great for injecting conditional HTML.  There is Jade / Mustache and others. The choice is yours.  Also like @tleon say's there is also the Ajax route..

Comment: @tleon I need to do this server-side because the API that I am making this request to requires an API token. They do not provide a read-only API token, so I was hoping to keep the token server side, make the request from the server, then serve the relevant html to the user.

Comment: @hungerstar I'm using an HTML/CSS template that is compatible with Express. I'm very new to this sort of development, so I'm not sure exactly what this template is capable of.

Comment: @user275615 there should be a way to pass data to your template. So you would check what the API returns and then set the class and then pass that class to the template. I don't know what _"compatible"_ is. You'll need to be more specific if you'd like additional help from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really give enough information in my initial question but I was able to figure out how to do what I was intending so I thought I'd post what I came across.

Please note, the ONLY reason that this needed to be done server side - and not in client side JS - is because I needed to send API requests to a service requiring API tokens. This service does not offer the ability to give out read-only API tokens, so exposing the master API token in client side Javascript is a large security issue (anyone using developer tools would be able to have full control over the service).

Using express as our node server to serve the static, I added an `app.get` line to listed for /getStatus:

`app.get('/getStatus', function (req, res){
....
});`

This function would make a request to the API in question, and return a json response.

The rest was done with client side Javascript. 

`$(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('http://' + window.location.hostname + ':8080/getStatus', function(status){
          $('response').html(status);`

From the last line there, `status` will contain the JSON object with the relevant details I needed. Then it was just a matter of using `document.getElementById(id).className = "the class name";`

Thanks to those who posted comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, just use a templating engine, Lookup [Pug Templating Engine](http://pugjs.org)